# How to remove only ONCE a min element that is repeated in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, numpy-ndarray

Lets say we have x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,5,5]]). I want to remove the min element in each array and even if repeated to only remove it once so that I can get x = np.array([[2,3,4],[6,5,5]]). How do i do it?

I can succesfully remove the min, but it removes all the min elements and gives me np.array([2,3,4,6]) and probably need to do a np.reshape after that but thats a detail. I used something like that:

x[np.where(x != np.min(x,axis=1,keepdims=True))]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 5, 5]])

def delete_first_min(arr: np.array):
    min_indexes = np.where(arr == np.min(arr))[0]
    first_min_index = min_indexes[0]
    return np.delete(arr, first_min_index) 
    # short: return np.delete(arr, np.where(arr == np.min(arr))[0][0]) 
    

x = np.apply_along_axis(delete_first_min, 1, x)

print(x)

>> [[2 3 4]
>>  [6 5 5]]
```

`np.where(arr == np.min(arr))[0]` returns an array of indices of the elements with min values, so subscripting it with `[0]` again returns the first min element.